# Text is displayed inverted while changing Coordinate system in HTML5 Canvas ie., drawing with y-axis value increasing upwards

Tags: html

```
context.translate(0, offsetY);
context.scale(1, -1);
```

The result of providing -1 as scale’s method second argument is that the whole image is created for inverted y coordinate. This applies to text too. So placing the text in a given coordinates after changing the transformations is not working properly as the text is displayed inverted.

So How to display text in a canvas after changing the coordinate system (inverted)?